# MountEmulatedStorage() Zygote SELinux get_category error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, runtime-error

```
12-15 01:08:43.226 30125-30125/? E/Zygote: MountEmulatedStorage()
12-15 01:08:43.226 30125-30125/? E/Zygote: v2
12-15 01:08:43.271 30125-30125/? E/SELinux: [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
```

I got this error, maybe someone knows how to solve?

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the probleme I just disabled then enabled usb du

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31305169)